# SAPUI5 Treetable height rendering

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have the following issue : I have the following structure of my view :
treetable inside a fragment, fragment inside the view.

The treetable has the properties

```
TreeTable id="TreeTable" selectionMode="Single" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" selectionBehavior="RowOnly">
```

Data is coming from `JsonModel`

The treetable is not rendered in the full height . after i scroll , close the page and open it again, the it renders correctly.
Any tips ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if

```
<App id="app"><App>
```

is present in the App.view.xml. It was what causing similar troubles in my case.